# Presto unable to create injector because Configuration property 'cordinator' was not used

Tags: presto

Installed presto on single machine cluster when starting presto getting this error.
com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'cordinator' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

1 error
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) Configuration property 'cordinator' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:241)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:115)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:67)
```

here is the config properties.

```
cordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be `coordinator`, not `cordinator`.